Multiple query result attachments using sp_dbmail in Sql Server
I have been trying to find a way to achieve one of the following scenarios using T-Sql:

send an e-mail with 1 excel attachment but 2 sheets (each sheet to
have results from 2 different queries)
send one e-mail with multiple excel/csv's, each having results from
separate queries?

For example:
I have been trying to use sp_dbmail to achieve this but it only sends one attachment in the email.
-- Send the e-mail with the query results in attach
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients="Your email",
@query=@qry,
@subject='Client list',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'result.csv',
@query_result_separator=',',@query_result_width =32767,
@query_result_no_padding=1

For an example of the ask:
@query1 = 'select * from tableA'
@query2 = 'select * from tableB'

I have an excel spreadsheet called 'excel1.xlsx' I want to be able to send @query1 results in sheet 1 of the spreadsheet and @query2 results in sheet 2 of the spreadsheet.
(OR)
Alternatively, I want to be able to send the results of the two queries in two separate excel files or csvs
Is this possible?

The simple answer is, don't use T-SQL for this; that isn't what it's designed for. Use a reporting tool. SQL Server has SSRS, for example.
